# Incorrect behaviour in program that calculates prime numbers

Tags: lua

This program insists that 35 is a prime number even though, going through it step-by-step, the program *should* reach the point where it calculates 35%5 and then ignore the number (because the result is 0.) I haven't checked every single number but it seems to display only primes otherwise (except for numbers that are anologous to 35 like 135.)

```
print ('How many prime numbers do you require?')
primes = io.read("*n")

print ('Here you go:')

num,denom,num_primes=2,2,0

while num_primes<primes do
   if denom<num then
      if num%denom==0 then
         num=num+1
      else
         denom=denom+1
      end
   else
      print(num)
      num=num+1
      num_primes=num_primes+1
      denom=2
   end
end
```

Sample output:

```
  How many prime numbers do you require?
  50
  Here you go:
  2
  3
  5
  7
  11
  13
  17
  19
  23
  27
  29
  31
  35
  37
  41
  43
  47
  53
  59
  61
  67
  71
  73
  79
  83
  87
  89
  95
  97
  101
  103
  107
  109
  113
  119
  123
  127
  131
  135
  137
  139
  143
  147
  149
  151
  157
  163
  167
  173
  179
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't resetting `denom` in the `%` case.

```
if num%denom==0 then
    num=num+1
else
```

So when you fall-through this test you start testing the next number starting from the previous denominator instead of from `2` again.

Simple debugging print lines in the loop printing out `denom` and `num` would have shown this to you (as, in fact, that's exactly how I found it). You only need to three prime numbers output to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, set `denom=2` after `num=num+1`

```
    print ('How many prime numbers do you require?')
primes = io.read("*n")

print ('Here you go:')

num,denom,num_primes=2,2,0

while num_primes<primes do
   if denom<num then
      if num%denom==0 then
         num=num+1
         denom=2
      else
         denom=denom+1
      end
   else
      print(num)
      num=num+1
      num_primes=num_primes+1
      denom=2
   end
end
```